# Efficient way of creating tab items containing user controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, initialization

I have a tab control and a number of tab items that are populated programatically and contain a custom control. At the minute each custom control is instantiated and `initializeComponent` is called on every user control when the tab control is created.

I suspect this is a bad way of doing it as some of the user controls can contain huge amounts of data, initialise database connections etc. I want to make this as efficient as possible. What I want to do is minimise the amount of work done by each user control until the tab it is located on is actually selected and visible to the user.

After digging around I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/217022/Delaying-Element-Initialization-for-Collapsed-Cont) detailing delayed initialisation for collapsed controls. I have managed to get this working for my tabs, but then after some more digging I managed to find the `Loaded` and `Unloaded` events. Would I be able to achieve delayed initization by simply removing `initializeComponent` from the user controls constructor and adding it to the `Loaded` event handler?

Also ideally what I want to be able to do is un initialize the user control when the `unloaded` event fires, until the next time the `loaded` event fires. Is there a way to reverse the xaml loading that occurs during initializeComponent?

I realise this may not be a trivial answer but I would appreciate any guidance/help.

Please let me know if you require anymore information.

Comment: you want to support load data on demand (when user select a tab) and unload it when user selects some other tab?

Comment: What I want to do is initialize the control when the user selects the tab. and then "unload" the xaml when the user leaves the tab.